# Serialize an "un serializable" object

Tags: c#, .net

I got some types and I really need to serialize an instance of these types, but they are not marked as serializable and I can't modify them. So I'm looking for a kind of deep dump memory save. I've try the BinaryFormatter etc, but they also require the serializable attribute...

Any ideas ? Haven't found a lot of things for my particular case... :'(

Comment: Use other serializers which don't require `Serializable` attribute such as XmlSerializer, JavascriptSerializer, DataContractSerializer, DataContractJsonSerializer etc.

Comment: @EmmanuelIstace what datatype are you trying to serialize?

Comment: Serializing anything by e.g. a memory dump isn't the issue - it's deserializing that tends to be the issue (if you expect the deserilized version to have any sensible behaviour)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most logical way to do this is to create a new object that is serializable that contains all the attributes of the un-serializable object. Then add functions to construct an instance of your object from the un-serializable object and vice-versa.

Comment: That's what I don't want to do... The object tree is really huge and complex, anyway, if there's no other way to do it...

Comment: If it's too huge and complex to extract the data into a class for serializing, how can you expect it to work via built-in serialization?

Comment: That's why I was looking for something like "deep memory dump", a bit like in unmanged language. :/

Comment: (I'm actually working with one of the worst code I've seen in my life... and the refactoring will cost too much... have to do with... :'( )

Comment: @EmmanuelIstace: There isn't really any such thing, even in unmanaged languages. Complex objects rarely sit in contiguous memory in a canonicalized form.

Answer (score 1):

[Serializable] is not a must for serialization, and for binary serialization, this is not needed.

Comment: Indeed, for the serialization itself no, but I need to use a BinaryFormatter to get a byte[] from my object.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [protobuf-net:Fast, portable, binary serialization for .NET](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/)

Code samples:

```
// write to a file
Serializer.Serialize(outputStream, person);

...

// read from a file
var person = Serializer.Deserialize<Person>(inputStream);
```

Comment: Need attribute on the class and on the field according to the site : http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/GettingStarted and I can't change my data model. (even just adding attributes).

Comment: @EmmanuelIstace, thanks for the info. I did not realize that attribute must be offered. Good info!